# Inverse Permutation Python Program not giving correct output

Tags: python

With this code that I've posted, If I were to run "python inverse_permutation.py 5 3 4 0 1 2" I would receive "3 4 5 1 2 0", which is correct, but when I run the program to test all of the python programs for correctness, I receive this following inequality causing my answer to be incorrect: self.assertEquals(got, sought) AssertionError: '3 4 5 1 2 0 \n' != '3 4 5 1 2 0\n'
I interpreted this as an extra space between the 0 and the \n causing the issue. I cannot figure out where the extra space is coming from. I have spent hours trying to correct this, but have not found anything.

```
import stdio
import sys
import stdarray

perm = []
for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    perm += [int(sys.argv[i])]
n = len(perm)
exists = stdarray.create1D(n, False)
for i in range(n):
    if (perm[i] < 0) or (perm[i] >= n) or exists[perm[i]]:
        stdio.writeln("Not a permutation")
        sys.exit(0)
    exists[perm[i]] = True
permInverted = [0] * n
for i in range(n):
    permInverted[perm[i]] = i
for element in permInverted:
    stdio.write(str(element) + ' ')
stdio.writeln()
```

Comment: Second to last line writes space even after the last element.

Comment: How can I fix that in such a way where it removes that space but keeps everything that is correct intact?

Comment: Something like `stdio.write(' '.join(str(element) for element in permInverted))` instead of the last for-loop should help.

Comment: Thank you for giving such helpful answers.  That seems to have removed the space, but now I am getting this as an output: 3 4 5 1 2 03 4 5 1 2 03 4 5 1 2 03 4 5 1 2 03 4 5 1 2 03 4 5 1 2 0

Comment: I wrote: "instead of the last for-loop". Not in the last for-loop.